# $X:N(100,25)$, Find: $P(95\leq X\leq 106.75)$, $P(X>92)$ and $P(X\leq x) = 10\%$

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

$X$ is normally distributed random variable with mean $100$ and variance $25$. $X:N(100,25)$.

a) Calculate: $P(95\leq X\leq 106.75)$ and $P(X>92)$

b) Find $x$ such that $P(X\leq x) = 10\% $

This is how I solved it:

a)

$P(95\leq X\leq 106.75)=P(\frac{95-100}{5} \leq X^*\leq \frac{106.75-100}{5})=\Phi(1.35)-\Phi(-1)=0.4115 + 0.3413=0.7528$

Z-score: $z(92)=\frac{92-100}{5}=-1.6$

$P(X>92)=\Phi(-1.6)+0.5=0.4452+0.5=0.9452$

b)

$P(X\leq x) = 10\% $

$P(X\leq x) = 0.1 $

Z-score: $z(x)=\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}=0.1$ and from this expression I get that $x=100.5$

Would appreciate if someone could check if this is correct..

Comment: If $x=100.5$ then $P(X\le x)$ should be about $0.5$

Comment: Sorry i just cant seem to find where is my mistake

Comment: Looking here http://www.z-table.com/ I got $-1.28$ for $\frac{x-100}{25}=0.1$ therefore $x\approx 68$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[here](http://www.z-table.com/) $z$-score table I look for $\frac{106.75-100}{25}=0.27$,
$z$-score is $0.6064$

and for $\frac{95-100}{25}=-0.2$,  $z$-score is $0.4207$

So  $P(95\leq X\leq 106.75)=0.6064-0.4207=0.1857$

$P(X>92)=1-P(X\leq 92)=0.6255$

For the second part you do an inverse research on that table until you see a value close to $0.1$, that is $0.1003$ which is related to $-1.28$

Therefore $\frac{x-100}{25}=-1.28\to x = 68$

Hope this helps

Comment: Shouldn't you divide with 5 when looking for z score?

Comment: @untitled Maybe this is why you got the wrong results